# how to convert the html files into bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As per the below code, by default home tab is showing blank. Content will display below when we click on product ordering tab. I have written this code in Javascript. But when i tried to convert these into bootstrap im struggling more to create this.
Anybody can help to resolve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="images/style.css" />-->
<style>
.wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px; 
    width: 100%;  
}
.container{
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    width: 900px;  
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
.menu_container{    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 900px;
}
.middle_container{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 900px;
}
.middle_container_left{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 246px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.middle_container_right{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 580px;
    height: 300px;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    float:left;
}
.menu_font{
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;cursor:hand;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #8eaf64;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;  
    color: white;
}
.menu_font:hover{
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;cursor:hand;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-weight:bold;   
    color: white;
    background-color:#64A70B !important;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}

.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 63px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 6px;
    background-color: #85a857; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 2px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: -5px; 
}


.green{
color: green;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function show_menu(elementId) { 
 document.getElementById("home").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("id2").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}

function show_left_menu(elementId) { 
 document.getElementById("quick_add").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("solution_builder").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("bulk_load").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("product_search").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("saved_cart").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("view_favorites").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">Demo</h2>

        <div class="menu_container">
            <div class="menu_font" onclick="show_menu('home');">Home</div>

            <div class="menu_font" onclick="show_menu('id2');">Product Ordering</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="middle_container">
            <div id="home" style="height: 300px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_container" id="id2"  style="display:none">
            <div class="middle_container_left">
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
                    <li style="padding:10px;height:20px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" onclick="show_left_menu('quick_add');">Quick Add</li>
                    <li style="padding:10px;height:20px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" onclick="show_left_menu('solution_builder');">Solution Builder</li>
                    <li style="padding:10px;height:20px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" onclick="show_left_menu('bulk_load');">Bulk Load</li>
                    <li style="padding:10px;height:20px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" onclick="show_left_menu('product_search');">Product Search</li>
                    <li style="padding:10px;height:20px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" onclick="show_left_menu('saved_cart');">Saved Cart</li>
                    <li style="padding:10px;height:20px;" onclick="show_left_menu('view_favorites');">View Favorites</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="middle_container_right" id="quick_add">
                <h2>Quick Add:</h2>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 300px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Item Name:</td>
                        <td>                                                        
                            <input list="product_name" name="item_name">
                              <datalist id="product_name">
                                <option value="112-800-00000">
                                <option value="112-700-00000">
                                <option value="700-800-00000">
                                <option value="100-800-00000">
                                <option value="900-800-00000">
                                <option value="600-800-00000">
                                <option value="08000BK07045">
                                <option value="08000BK04045">
                                <option value="08000BK06045">
                              </datalist>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12   ">
                                <div class=" dispinline col-sm-offset-5 col-xs-offset-1  col-xs-4 col-sm-2 searchlabel">Enable Search </div>
                                <div class="onoffswitch dispinline "> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
                                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td style="height: 10px;"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Quantity:</td>
                        <td><input type="textbox" name="Quantity"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td style="height: 10px;"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add Item to Cart" name="add_item_to_cart"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td style="height: 10px;"></td></tr>

                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="middle_container_right" id="solution_builder" style="display:none;">solution builder content</div>
            <div class="middle_container_right" id="bulk_load" style="display:none;">Bulk Load content</div>
            <div class="middle_container_right" id="product_search" style="display:none;">Product Search content</div>
            <div class="middle_container_right" id="saved_cart" style="display:none;">Saved cart content</div>
            <div class="middle_container_right" id="view_favorites" style="display:none;">View Favorites content</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MY Bootstrap code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
        .navbar {
          margin-bottom: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
        }
        
        /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
        .row.content {height: 450px}
        
        /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
        .sidenav {
          padding-top: 20px;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
          height: 100%;
        }
        
        /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
        footer {
          background-color: #555;
          color: white;
          padding: 15px;
        }
        
        /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
          .sidenav {
            height: auto;
            padding: 15px;
          }
          .row.content {height:auto;} 
        }
     .nav-tabs { border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD; }
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover { border-width: 0; }
        .nav-tabs > li > a { border: none; color: #666; }
            .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover { border: none; color: #4285F4 !important; background: transparent; }
            .nav-tabs > li > a::after { content: ""; background: #4285F4; height: 2px; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: -1px; transition: all 250ms ease 0s; transform: scale(0); }
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a::after, .nav-tabs > li:hover > a::after { transform: scale(1); }
    .tab-nav > li > a::after { background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: #fff; }
    .tab-pane { padding: 15px 0; }
    .tab-content{padding:20px}
    
    .card {background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); margin-bottom: 30px; }
    body{ background: #EDECEC; padding:50px}
    
    
    
      </style>
      <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <!--<div class="container-fluid text-center">    -->
    <div class="container">    
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" style="border: 1px solid red;">
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
          <h1 style="text-align: center;">DEMO</h1>
          <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid red;width:100%;">
                                        <!-- Nav tabs --><div class="card">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                                            <!--<li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>-->
                                        </ul>
    
                                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                                        <div class="tab-content">
                                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"></div>
                                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"><h2>Quick Add:</h2>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Item Name:</td>
                            <td>                                                        
                                <!--<input list="product_name" name="item_name">
                                  <datalist id="product_name">
                                    <option value="112-800-00000">
                                    <option value="112-700-00000">
                                    <option value="700-800-00000">
                                    <option value="100-800-00000">
                                    <option value="900-800-00000">
                                    <option value="600-800-00000">
                                    <option value="08000BK07045">
                                    <option value="08000BK04045">
                                    <option value="08000BK06045">
                                  </datalist>-->
             <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="sm">
          </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12   ">
                                    <div class=" dispinline col-sm-offset-5 col-xs-offset-1  col-xs-4 col-sm-2 searchlabel">Enable Search </div>
                                    <!--<div class="onoffswitch dispinline "> 
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
                                        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                                            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>-->
            <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
                                </div>  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td style="height: 10px;"></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Quantity:</td>
                            <td><input type="textbox" name="Quantity"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td style="height: 10px;"></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add Item to Cart" name="add_item_to_cart"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td style="height: 10px;"></td></tr>
    
                    </table>
        </div>
                                            <!--<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages"></div>
                                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings"></div>-->
                                        </div>
    </div>
                                    </div>
     </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
      <p>Footer Text</p>
    </footer>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure where to start here. But one main cause for unexpected display results may be that `bootstrap-toggle.min.css` is *after* your embedded styling so the default bootstrap CSS will override your custom styling which I am assuming is the opposite to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know exactly what your saying but you could just line for line convert it by hand to a seperate language thats compatable, im sure theres a better way to do this but this is how i personaly do it.